EVM Transaction Issue: Inconsistent Out of Gas Errors
I'm facing issue with Inconsistent Out of Gas Errors on BSC Testnet
This is fail transaction: https://testnet.bscscan.com/tx/0x669f2e8150825e9be9e0ec7da13b112691082ee43c0227afbb6b4dcbf08bec6c
Although the bsc scan shows that transaction is "execution reverted", when I check on tenderly, the reason is "out of gas"
This is success transaction:
https://testnet.bscscan.com/tx/0x15b8eb359269a63300c221e4b4fd35d2f9594c864e7bb00ebe5b0853130b415e
The logic on both transaction are the same, the data are not 100% identical, but they are similar.
My question is:

What is the main reason for this issue?

If I need to supply more gas, What is suitable number in %, because the gas cost is similar.


This is describe what tx does:
contract A {
   function createNFT(name, symbol, uri,... ) external {
     // data = encode(name, symbol, uri,...)
     // create proxyContract(implAddress, data)
     // assign mapping: nft[proxyAddress] = (name, symbol, uri,...)
     // emit Log
   }
}


We can only speculate without the source code. Some opcodes have different costs depending on the storage changes. Similarly with calldata costs.

I updated my question, including the description of what tx does in transaction. Please help to take a look inside 2 tx details, both of them cost 98.51% of gas limit? I wonder why it reverted with the issue out of gas while not using the full gas limit?

I understand gas cost will be different even the logic is the same, it can depend on calldata costs, but it will not cost too much when the calldata is similar. And my success tx didn't use full gas, and the fail tx didn't use full gas too. So why it reverts, how much do I need to supply more?

I remember that the transaction was much more complicated, a contract was deployed and a couple of proxys are executed. Wallet usually provide a method to estimate a transaction that should simulate the execution and return a good approximation. It is possible to indicate a higher gas limit. In that case the unused gas will be returned after the transaction execution.

I tried fork node, at the same block number and with the same transaction data, it executed well on my local by estimate gas or broadcast. It provides the same trace debug with the fail transaction but it didn't revert.
You may saw 2 proxies were executed 2 d-calls: the first one is proxy of factory contractA, the second one is the nft contract which was created and execute initialize function

In solidity if an internal call fails it will revert the whole transaction. The trace in bscscan showed a internal call failing because of out of gas. So I'd try increasing the gas limit. The estimation failure could be some bug in the implementation.
